# How to bound logarithm with variable base? (asymptotics)

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

**Problem:** For any $n>1$ let
$\theta(n) = \big( 1 - (\ln n + 1)^{-1} \big)^{-1}$, where $\ln$ is the natural logarithm. Show that for some $k$ (not depending on $n$) it holds that
$\log_{\theta(n)}n \in \mathcal{O}((\log n)^k)$, i.e. there exists a positive real number $c$ such that $\log_{\theta(n)}n \leq c (\log n)^k$ for all large enough $n$ (where $\log$ is with respect to any base, e.g. 2).

*What I know:* k=1 is probably not good enough, but $k=2$ seems to be fine (looking at plots).

*Preferably:* $k$ as small as possible.

*Motivation:* If the claim is true, then I have an asymptotically fast algorithm for encoding certain algebraic geometry codes (error-correction).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$y=\log_{\theta(n)}(n)=\frac{\log (n)}{\log (\theta (n))}$$
$$\theta (n)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\log (n)+1}}\implies y=\frac{\log (n)}{\log \left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{\log (n)+1}}\right)}=-\frac {\log (n)}{\log\left({1-\frac{1}{\log (n)+1}}\right)}=-\frac{\log (n)}{\log \left(\frac{\log (n)}{\log (n)+1}\right)}$$

$$y=\frac{\log (n)}{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{\log (n)}\right)}$$

Make $n=e^x$, simplify and use Taylor series for large $x$.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I could/should have figured it out myself.